# Jquery/javascript, filtering html object from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filter

I have this piece of html:

```
<div id="1">
  <div class="text">
     Text for div 2 
  </div>
<img src="images/image1.jpg"></img>
</div>

<div id="2">
  <div class="text">
    Text in div 2
  </div>
  <img src="images/image2.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Which I grab with a simple .ajax-call

```
var html = $.ajax({
         url: "htmlsnippet.html",
         cache: false,
         async: false,
         dataType: "html"
         }).responseText;
```

If I filter it with:

```
var htmlFiltered = $(html).filter("#1");
```

it works just fine, I get the whole div with id="1",
but if I use:

```
var htmlFiltered = $(html).filter("#1 .text");
```

the htmlFiltered variable is an empty object.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't think IDs starting with a number are valid

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should store it this way:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "htmlsnippet.html",
   cache: false,
   async: false,
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(data){
      html = data;
   }
}
```

EDIT: Your way of obtaining html works, but it's not recommended.
You can't grab your last element because you're using `filter` instead of `find`, so you should have:

```
var htmlFiltered = $(html).find("#1 .text");
```

instead of

```
var htmlFiltered = $(html).filter("#1 .text");
```

Also W3C recommends not to have numeric IDs.

**EDIT 2**: This should work:

```
var htmlFiltered = $(html).filter("#1").find(".text");
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer and removed the comment but forgot to remove the downvote. Fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks, Edgar, but it doesn't work. I renamed the divs and used your method of obtaining and storing the html, but .filter still won't grab any elements except the numbered divs. .find doesn't work at all.

Comment: Thanks,very much ! That worked. I hate to be a nag, but can you explain how you got to this solution ? I'm having a hard time understanding what happens to the html object once I grab it with Ajax and use filter on it.

Comment: .filter only on the nodes that you are selecting, **not their children**, and .find does the opossite, find in the children, not the nodes you're selecting. So, $(html).filter("#1 .text");
was selecting wrong, cause .text is not a parent, is a child. With $(html).filter("#1").find(".text"), we're _filtering_ only the parents who whave id 1, and its children that are .text. I hope my explanation is understandable

Comment: Yes, I think I understand. So the .text divs are not part of the set defined by the html-object, only their parent divs are.

Comment: Exactly. Glad to have helped you

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need any special functionality given by the full `$.ajax` method, you should give `$.load()` a try:

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Answer (score 2):

This works for me :

```
$.get(url,function(content) {
    var content = $(content).find('div.contentWrapper').html();
    ...
}
```