# fetch URL content and grab table rows from HTML, possibly convert into RSS feed using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rss, titanium, titanium-alloy

Using Appcelerator Alloy Titanium:

Say some website has tables for events, news, articles like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8MVUM/1/

```
<table class="sectiontable" style="width:300px">
<tr class="sectiontableentry1">
  <td>1.1.2014</td>
  <td>New Year Party</td> 
</tr>
<tr class="sectiontableentry2">
  <td>25.12.2013</td>
  <td>Christmas</td> 
</tr>
</table>
```

Would it be possible for javascript/jquery/underscore/etc
- to use AJAX to grab a website from a URL
- and remove all the HTML and grab the table and rows based on class/id ?
- (optional) and "possibly" convert the table into rss ? which can be used in an rss parser.

Comment: i found something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898011/jquery-javascript-filtering-html-object-from-ajax-response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery function "load"](https://api.jquery.com/load/). Then used this like:

```
$( "#tables" ).load( "tables.html" );
```

then you can process them with DOM:

```
document.getElementsByClassName( "sectiontable" )
```

or with jquery css-like selection

```
$( ".sectiontable" ).some_method()
```