# How to display in html, return data in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, filter

```
                success: function(htmldata) {

                 var $response = $(htmldata);

                 var oneval = $response.filter('#res3').html();
                 var subval = $response.filter('#res4').html();
```

Can someone help me how to display this in html?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/5898011/3788456 for your answer also take note the amount of detail in the question.

Comment: Ok, ill check it out

Comment: When you get data, define it by dataType: "html"