# Filtering a PHP response

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

What I'm trying to do  is filtering the response of a php page.
for instance when I send a request to domain.com/example.php, in return I get what i asked for plus some extra content which I don't want to embed in my div.
I don't need the entire content
I'm only looking for a link inside a button

Here's an example:

[Response](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/dl.php?fileName=8592&lang=en-us)

[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbKzn.png)

I need to filter the whole response and only get the href inside the download button.

I created my own proxy to bypass the cross origin issue.
here's the code that return the whole page inside the Div with an Id of infodown:

`$('#infodown').load('https://myownproxyserver.herokuapp.com/https://tb.rg-adguard.net/dl.php?fileName=8592&lang=en-us)`

I believe that it's possible to show only what I want since I got the whole thing stored in a variable
any ideas?

Comment: Create jQuery element form response HTML content and then traverse it like you would with the current DOM. `$.get("url").then((data) => $(data).find(".my-element"))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery/javascript, filtering html object from ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898011/jquery-javascript-filtering-html-object-from-ajax-response)

Comment: Can you explain more please?

Comment: You request the html content form the server then pass it to jQuery function `$` to instantiate a jquery object which then enables you to traverse this html like you would with any other element on the page enabling you to only get the elements you need.

Comment: i was not able to implement your code into mine, can i get a push?

Comment: Go to any site that supports jquery (your own but must be hosted on a server) and run the following script in browser console: `fetch(window.location.href).then(res => res.text()).then(jQuery).then(($element) => console.log($element.find("div")));`

Comment: im so lost 
can you please check the example i gave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
fetch("https://tb.rg-adguard.net/dl.php?fileName=8592&lang=en-us")
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(html => {
       // Same as $(html).find(".buttond > a")
       const div = document.createElement("div");
       div.innerHTML = html;
       return div.querySelector(".buttond > a");
    })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```